# Why image loads on text in webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

```
web= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
 WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
    webSettings.setTextSize (WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL) ;
    web.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<p dir=\"rtl\" align=\"right\">" + desc + "</p>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

`[image]

i have a problem in the webview that when it loads the image it's loaded on the text which makes the text corrupted as shown in the image knowing that both i get them by connection to service 
any ideas how to solve this

Comment: Can you post code what you have tried. without showing code. How can we help you.

Comment: it's a simple webview that i load in it html tags

Comment: create an html file put all the contents. Try to see how it looks like using browser.  If the html file in browser looks exactly same as that of webview in android then problem is in html file and you have to change it.

Comment: the html is working properly on other browsers !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with android webviews ,You can solve it with putting the height to  tag.
--> height="imageHeight" ..or a margin-bottom equal to his height..
this is not a good solution but is the is the only one I found.